# How can I click an element in Python Selenium after finding it?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I am creating a script that gets the attribute of an element and if it's true it clicks it. But I keep running into an error.

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

choice1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[1]/ng-include/label')
choice2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[2]/ng-include/label')
choice3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[3]/ng-include/label')
choice4 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[4]/ng-include/label')
choice5 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[5]/ng-include/label')

for i in choice1:
    if i.get_attribute('data-correct') == 'true':
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[1]/ng-include/label').click()
    else:
        pass

for i in choice2:
    if i.get_attribute('data-correct') == 'true':
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[2]/ng-include/label').click()
    else:
        pass

for i in choice3:
    if i.get_attribute('data-correct') == 'true':
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[3]/ng-include/label').click()
    else:
        pass

for i in choice4:
    if i.get_attribute('data-correct') == 'true':
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[4]/ng-include/label').click()
    else:
        pass
```

This is the code on the webpage:

```
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Earned three college degrees and supported himself as a small businessman - Google values entrepreneurship.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="true">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Has several years of work experience, and enjoys volunteering for Habitat for Humanity - Google values these character traits.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Recently graduated from Harvard University - Google is known for hiring the best and the brightest.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Worked as an independent contractor in different areas of the computer industry - Google values versatility.</p></span>
</label>
```

I tried printing out the choices and they did give me the correct values but I get this error when I run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Studify.py", line 106, in <module>
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[1]/ng-include/label').click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I'm not using a list so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath return a list, find_element_by_xpath the first match, check documentation to know functions

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not answering your original question but I would recommend using [Helium](https://github.com/mherrmann/selenium-python-helium). It is a good alternative to Selenium and is much easier to use in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I was using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` which is wrong. Since elements is plural and returns a list of elements. I simply changed `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` to `driver.find_element_by_xpath` just removed the (s). Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this issue in the future.